# How to check if input is numeral when using Thymeleaf and Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Currency converter and if I enter a string into the input field I get an error before any of my checks can be used as the input value doesn't match what is declared in the controller. My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String convertCurrency(@RequestParam String toCurrency, Double amount, Model model,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        
        if (!(amount == null)&&(amount== (double)amount)) {
            if (amount > 0) {
                try {
                    ConvertionCurrency currency = currencyService.getCurrencyRate(toCurrency);
                    Double conRate = currency.getConvertionRateToEUR();

                    Double result = amount * conRate;
                    System.out.println(result);
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("result", result);
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successClass", "alert-success");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "A positive number is needed");
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-danger");
                }
```

Double amount is the attribute in question.

In the HTML page the input is nothing special:

```
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount"
                                id="amount" name="amount">
                        </div>
```

I can see that the problem is that the error is caused in the declaration of the variables.

So my question is how do I check the input before it goes to the Controller?

Comment: Does your input element need to be of type text, and how many decimal places do you have to work with? `<input type="number" step="0.01">` Would allow you to enter numeric values with two decimals, for example. [Input type number documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot I could make the input tye a number. This is the answer to my question.

Comment: Excellent. I will post it as an answer so you can accept it and so it will be of use to others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your input element need to be of type text, and how many decimal places do you have to work with? `<input type="number" step="0.01">` would allow you to enter numeric values with two decimals, for example. [Input type number documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to verify the type of the input field before submitting the request, or add spring's verifier

Comment: This is not the answer, but the comment. Please consider to remove your answer and write the comment, otherwise provide the full answer "How to check the value before it hit the controller?"

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing that is to take a `String` as the method arguments.

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String convertCurrency(@RequestParam String toCurrency, String amount, Model model,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    try {
        Double foo = Double.valueOf(amount);
        try {
            // Your code here
        } catch (...) {...}
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Handle your error when the input is a String
    }
```